# re-arrange UI by array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

So, I have a calendar, only with the weekdays, monday through sunday. I want to do implement something that, when you click an arrow(left or right) the UI gets rearranged, so , basically, we have

```
< monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday >
```

if i press the arrow pointing to the left, I want to re-arrange to UI to look like ->

```
< sunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday >
```

basically, start with the last index in the array
I have the following

```
<ul className="weekday">
  <li> <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-left" /> </li>
    {this.state.weekDays.map(day => <li key={day}> {day} </li>)}
  <li onClick={this.handleIncrement}> <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-right" /> </li>
</ul>
```

here i render all the weekdays in a ul from the weekdays array

`weekDays: [ 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun' ]`

i also have a  `currenyDay:0;` in my state, under the array 
and as you can see a onClick on the right arrow which increases the currentday because on right arrow i have to increase the currentday by 1, the function looks like

```
handleIncrement = () => {
  this.state.currentDay = this.state.currentDay +1;
}
```

however, it does nothing, it doesn't work at all, any ideeas why?

-------------------------- full code

```
class Calendar extends Component {
     state = { 
      weekDays: [ 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun' ],
      currentDay:0
    };

    handleIncrement = () => {
      this.state.currentDay = this.state.currentDay +1;
    }

    render() { 
        return (  
            <div className="calendar">
            <div className="col leftCol">
              <div className="content">
                <h1 className="date">My React.js Calendar</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col rightCol">
              <div className="content">
                {/* <div className="clearfix"></div> */}
                <ul className="weekday">
                  <li> <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-left" /> </li>
                    {this.state.weekDays.map(day => <li key={day}> {day} </li>)}
                  <li onClick={this.handleIncrement}> <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-right" /> </li>
                </ul>
                {/* <div className="clearfix"></div> */}
                {/* <div className="clearfix"></div> */}
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* <div className="clearfix"></div> */}
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Calendar;
```

Comment: you can't set `this.state` directly (except in the class's constructor), you have to use `this.setState`. (If changing that doesn't fix it, we're going to need to see more code though - ideally the entire component unless it's very big.)

Comment: I've tried putting setState and it didn't worked, i've put it back to how it was, i'm adding another comment with the full code

Comment: @RobinZigmond i have edited my initial question and added full code at the end! Maybe you can check?

Comment: @TempAcct4Stack - Except for incrementing it, your code doesn't use `currentDay` in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the purpose of `currentDay`, but it seems that it doesn't effect anything in the render.

I would implement this by altering the array in state. The main idea is that increment or decrement call [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) with an updater function. Use the updater function of `setState`, whenever you want to create a new state based on the previous one. We take the `weekDays` of the previous state, and produce a new array in the order we want.

```js
class Weekdays extends React.Component {
  state = {
    weekDays: [ 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun' ]
  };
  
  moveLeft = () => this.setState(({ weekDays: [head, ...tail] }) => ({
    weekDays: [...tail, head]
  }));
  
  moveRight = () => this.setState(({ weekDays }) => ({
    weekDays: [...weekDays.slice(-1), ...weekDays.slice(0, -1)]
  }));
  
  render() {
    const { weekDays } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <ul className="weekday">
        <li onClick={this.moveLeft}>&lt;</li>
        
          {this.state.weekDays.map(day => <li key={day}> {day} </li>)}
        
        <li onClick={this.moveRight}>&gt;</li>
      </ul>    
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Weekdays />,
  demo
);
```

```css
.weekday {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.weekday > li {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Holy... i'm so bad at React. I'm just getting started, thanks a lot, i've smoked 2 packs of ciggaretes trying to find a solution

Comment: My advice to you is to keep practicing and quit smoking :)